# How do you create, compile and use static and dynamic libraries in linux-like systems?

Tags: c, linux, macos, shared-libraries, static-libraries

this is my main question:

How do you create, compile and use static and dynamic libraries in linux-like systems? What is the difference between them?

Are there any good free tutorials explaining this stuff for a total idiota like me. I've only done c# programming before. I know a little C, C++ and Objective-C. I'm developing for iPhone but I'm trying to compile several libraries for the iPhone without much success. I understand so far (well at least the very basics) what a makefile is and how to modify one, I think i can create a static library using the following: `ar file1.o file2.o`, i though i had to do `CC file1.o file2.o` because they had to be linked together using some magic. In C# it was really simple you get the dll add reference and you're done. Here it seems so complicated.
Another question: How can i cross compile to another platform ARM for example? Especially those libraries which don't have that `./configure` thingy (which I know nothing about) for arm already set up.
Yet another one: What is `CFLAGS = -isysroot path/to/some/sdk`? What does it do?

Comment: > "several libraries for the iPhone" Your platform cannot be Linux. Change question's tags to include "Mac OS X" since it has different linking mechanisms.

Comment: I want to cross compile libraries for iPhone. I don't know what's the difference between mac and linux linking mechanism in fact I don't even know what a linking mechanism is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-shobj/) quite helpful. It has step-by-step instructions for building a shared object dynamic library. It has a couple minor mistakes in its example code and commands, but at least it *has* example code and commands.

Answer (score 4):

[How to Write Shared Libraries](http://people.redhat.com/~drepper/dsohowto.pdf) is about the best introduction to the topic that I've found.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed the link now.